# ACR35: APDU command select file returns status 6A 82 (file not found)

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am testing an ACR35 and I am having this issue with the provided SDK.

I have a DESFire EV1 card which has the following file structure:

```
[ Master File ]
      |
      |___ [ AID - F222222222  (Dedicated file) ]
                   |
                   |___ [ File id - 0001 (Elementary File) ]
```

I have verified that this file structure really exists on the card with another reader (Android device with integrated NFC reader).

I am selecting the DF (by its AID) with this code:

```
public void powerOn(){
    if (mReader.piccPowerOn(timeout, cardType)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "poweron true");
        byte[] test = ApduCommand.HexStringToByteArray("00A4040005F222222222");
        /*Transmit the command to the reader with timeout: 5 sec*/
        mReader.piccTransmit(timeout, test);
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "poweron false");
        powerOn();
    }
}
```

And I am waiting for the response here:

```
/* Set the PICC response APDU callback. */
mReader.setOnPiccResponseApduAvailableListener(new AudioJackReader.OnPiccResponseApduAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPiccResponseApduAvailable(AudioJackReader reader, byte[] responseApdu) {
        String resultHex = ApduCommand.ByteArrayToHexString(responseApdu);
        Log.i(TAG, "APDU response ("+current_status+")" + resultHex);

        if(resultHex.equals("9000")) {
            if (current_status == STATUS_SELECT_AID) {
                if (mReader.piccPowerOn(timeout, cardType)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "selecting file");
                    byte[] selFile = ApduCommand.HexStringToByteArray("00A40200020001");
                    current_status = STATUS_SELECT_FILE;
                    mReader.piccTransmit(timeout, selFile);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "timed out..");
                }
            }else if(current_status == STATUS_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (mReader.piccPowerOn(timeout, cardType)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "reading binary data");
                    byte[] readBinary = ApduCommand.HexStringToByteArray("00B0000000");
                    current_status = STATUS_READ_DATA;
                    mReader.piccTransmit(timeout, readBinary);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "timed out..");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here, I get a success status (`90 00`) on selecting the DF but I get a file not found status (`6A 82`) while selecting the file.

Log are as follows:

```
12-28 18:17:02.752 27298-28923/com.example.m1alesis.smartcardreader I/acrx: APDU response (0)9000
12-28 18:17:02.752 27298-28923/com.example.m1alesis.smartcardreader I/acrx: selecting file
12-28 18:17:03.412 27298-28949/com.example.m1alesis.smartcardreader I/acrx: APDU response (1)6A82
```

Using the same card and the exact same APDU commands on Android NFC reader mode works fine and I am able to select the file but ACR35 doesn't seem to like multiple sequential APDU commands.

Github project: https://github.com/rthapa/smartcardreader

Comment: Is there a reason why you call `piccPowerOn()` before trying to select the file? I'm not quite sure what that method does, but if it disables and re-enables power, then the DESFire application may no longer be selected.

Comment: @MichaelRoland That was it !!! It makes perfectly sense now. Wow I went through these codes like 100 times and couldn't figure out. Thank you, if you post this as answer I will accept it. It maybe useful to someone else in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `mReader.piccPowerOn(timeout, cardType)` between sending APDUs. The method `piccPowerOn()` will cause the reader to reset the DESFire card. Consequently, the application `F222222222` will no longer be selected when you execute the SELECT (by FID) command `00 A4 0200 02 0001`.